# How to add element to array at firestore database? (python)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

#### I need to add some value (val) to existing array in google.cloud.firestore document.

I found solution like that:

```
database.collection('collection_name').document('document_id').update({'array_name': firestore.ArrayUnion([val])})
```

where 'array_name' is name of array-type field in document with 'document_id' id in collection 'collection_name'.

That code used:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

and database is:

```
database = firestore.client()
```

But PyCharm says:

> Cannot find reference 'ArrayUnion' in 'firestore.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in PyCharm Indexes, something like that. Code could run and ArrayUnion worked, but IDE said that there are no function ArrayUnion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your imports are a little wrong. Try:

```py
import firebase_admin 
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

You can also read more in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

Full sample would be:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use a service account
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccount.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
```

I copied it straight from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't copied imports from my code that's why I wrote imports from my memory and these are wrong of course. At code I have right imports as in documentation. I will edit my post.